# Open activity from if statement Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get my android app to open my main activity if the result = login successful, when debugging result =Login successful\n" and it doesn't trigger my if statement bellow. I have seen a lot of apps using intents from button clicks so I'm not sure if this is possible as intents were giving me problems

```
         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("INSERT_RESULT", result);

            String r = result;
            if(r == "Login successful\n" ) {
                new MainActivity();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.e("INSERT_RESULT", result);

    if ("Login successful\n".equals(result)) {
        Context context = YourActivity.this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```